# How to get selected dropdown values in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select, dropdown

I am trying get selected values form two drop down lists.
But my code shows only first values(`<option>`) of the dropdown lists.

Even if I select the second option still I am getting the first value of the drop down list.

Here is the demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMOYGe

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* saving selected values in variables */
    var selected_destination = $('.text-one :selected').val();
    var selected_attraction_or_activity = $('.text-two :selected').val();

    /* Showing selected values when the button is clicked*/
    $('#attr_acti_btn').click(function(){
        alert (selected_destination);
        alert (selected_attraction_or_activity);
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = selected_destination;
 document.getElementById("attr_or_act_div").innerHTML = selected_attraction_or_activity;
    });

});
```

What I am doing wrong?
How can I get 2nd value if select the 2nd value and hit the button `Click to Show!`?

**Why the ******* I'm getting down votes for this question?
what's wrong with this question?**

Comment: put this `var selected_destination = $('.text-one :selected').val();
 var selected_attraction_or_activity = $('.text-two :selected').val();
` inside click event sample here https://jsfiddle.net/urpnerpu/

Comment: thanks.. that woks.. make this as answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: answered it happy coding mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put these

```
var selected_destination = $('.text-one :selected').val(); 
var selected_attraction_or_activity = $('.text-two :selected').val();
```

inside the click event. because you need to get the value of the selected option during the click event.and not during the loading of the elements.

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* saving selected values in variables */

  /* Showing selected values when the button is clicked*/
  $('#attr_acti_btn').click(function() {
    var selected_destination = $('.text-one :selected').val();
    var selected_attraction_or_activity = $('.text-two :selected').val();

    alert(selected_destination);
    alert(selected_attraction_or_activity);
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = selected_destination;
    document.getElementById("attr_or_act_div").innerHTML = selected_attraction_or_activity;
  });

});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/urpnerpu/)

Answer (score 1):

You missed a simple logic:

As you are changing the selected values,

```
$('#attr_acti_btn').click(function() {
  var selected_destination = $('.text-one :selected').val();
  var selected_attraction_or_activity = $('.text-two :selected').val();
  alert(selected_destination);
  alert(selected_attraction_or_activity);
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = selected_destination;
  document.getElementById("attr_or_act_div").innerHTML = selected_attraction_or_activity;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* saving selected values in variables */

    /* Showing selected values when the button is clicked*/
    $('#attr_acti_btn').click(function(){
  var selected_destination = $('.text-one :selected').val();
    var selected_attraction_or_activity = $('.text-two :selected').val();

        alert (selected_destination);
        alert (selected_attraction_or_activity);
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = selected_destination;
 document.getElementById("attr_or_act_div").innerHTML = selected_attraction_or_activity;
    });

});
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrPVvp)**